# Drupal 7 - Make a CCK Date field a required field

Tags: 7, entities

How do I make a CCK Date field a required field in hook_form_alter?

I have tried doing

```
function mycustommodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['field_birth_date']['und']['#required'] = TRUE;
    $form['field_birth_date']['und'][0]['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I was able to make it work on a CCK Text field:

```
$form['field_nickname']['und'][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Can you print_r($form_state); ?

Comment: What widget are you using to edit the field?

Comment: use devel and `dsm($form)` or `dpm($form)`: `$form['field_nickname']['#required'] = TRUE;`

Comment: @WestieUK I also tried $form_state['field']['field_birth_date']['und']['instance']['required'] = FALSE; but it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you meant $form_state['field']['field_birth_date']['und']['instance']['required'] = TRUE; and FALSE was just a typo?

Comment: @jvc26 Yup. Sorry about that.